# simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, encoding

I am testing my API from the postman.

**API- http://localhost:5005/abc/xyz**
**Method - POST** 
**data - {"q":"Hi"}**
 I am trying to check which encoding method is used and accordingly process further. I am getting above error.

```
def request_parameters(request):
if request.method.decode('utf-8', 'strict') == 'GET':
    return {
        key.decode('utf-8', 'strict'): value[0].decode('utf-8',
                                                       'strict')
        for key, value in request.args.items()}
else:
    content = request.content.read()
    try:
        return json.loads(content.decode('utf-8', 'strict'))
    except ValueError as e:
        logger.error("Failed to decode json during respond request. "
                     "Error: {}. Request content: "
                     "'{}'".format(e, content))
        raise
```